# How to aggregate some column while keeping others in Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset that contains `>100 variables` but to illustrate the problem I will simplify it as below.

[image]

I want to `groupby()` `colA`,`colB` and `sum()` `colD`, while taking the distinct values of `colC` and `colE`

i have tried something as below but as you would know this gives back only the columns I have grouped and the ones I have summed and never returns `colC` and `colE`

**approach1:** 
`df.groupby(['colA','colB').aggregate({'colC': sum})`

**approach2:** I could aggregate them like above and then join it later to the same table to get the result.

**approach3:** have all columns in groupby, but when I do so, I cannot group by on a value that is `Missing` like you can see in `colE`

What are my options?

**Correction**
**UPDATE:** I have just corrected the way I presented the data earlier, it was incorrect

```
data = [
    ["25-5-19", "cat1", "cat3", 10, 1],
    ["25-5-19", "cat1", "cat3", 20, 1],
    ["25-5-19", "cat1", "cat3", 30, 1],
    ["26-5-19", "cat2", "cat4", 50, 2],
    ["26-5-19", "cat2", "cat4", 100, 2],
    ["26-5-19", "cat2", "cat4", 10, 2],
    ["27-5-19", "cat1", "cat5", 40, None],
    ["27-5-19", "cat1", "cat5", 60, None]
]
```

`

Comment: I have a library for more complex dataframe manipulations inspired by knime. You can check it out to see if there is any function that can help your situation.

https://github.com/gokhangerdan/knime2python

Groupby function is at line 200.

Comment: *taking the distinct values of colC* do you want `nunique()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang,  your question helped me to get to the below solution that instantly worked for me.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need

```
df['New']=df.groupby(['colA','colB'])['colC'].transform('sum')
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to groupby() colA,colB and sum() colD, while taking the distinct values of colC and colE

So I believe you could use `set` in the aggregator and `reset_index()` after you're done:

```py
# dataframe data from example (+ extra `cat1` in ColC)
data = [
    ["25-5-19", "cat1", "cat1", 10, 1],
    ["25-5-19", "cat1", "cat3", 20, 1],
    ["25-5-19", "cat1", "cat3", 30, None],
    ["26-5-19", "cat2", "cat4", 50, 2],
    ["26-5-19", "cat2", "cat4", 100, 2],
    ["26-5-19", "cat2", "cat4", 10, 2]
] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['colA', 'colB', 'colC', 'colD', 'colE']) 

# aggregator sums over `colD` and gets distinct values of `colC` and `colE`
df.groupby(['colA', 'colB']).aggregate({'colD': sum, 'colC': set, 'colE': set}).reset_index()


| - | colA  |colB   | colE         | colD   | colC          |
|---|-------|-------|--------------|--------|---------------|
|0  |25-5-19|  cat1 |   {nan, 1.0} |  60    |  {cat3, cat1} |
|1  |26-5-19|  cat2 |   {2.0}      |  160   |   {cat4}      |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['colA', 'colB', 'colC', 'colD', 'colE']) 

df['colE'] = df['colE'].fillna(-1)# I replaced all NaN with -1 to avoid `function not reduce error`

df.groupby(['colA','colB']).aggregate({'colD':sum,'colC':np.unique,'colE':np.unique})
```